# How can I design a fraction as a image or other function in Xcode?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm a novice programmer, and I'm making a calculator now.
For the current situation, I can enter a number from the button and calculate them. I need a cursor, so I work a display as a `UITextView`.
 I want to import numbers from number buttons, change the number in the fraction box, and move the cursor in the fraction box and other numbers. And I want to design the fraction box like this image.

How can I design a fraction as a image or other function? Can I do this function in Xcode? If Xcode cannot be worked, please let me know which tool can be worked.
Sorry, but I don't want other answers like "³/₄".

[image: fraction]

Comment: The image is blank. Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: Can you try again?

Comment: Just I want to know how can I work fractions like this image.

Comment: You can do it natively, of course, but it's non-trivial. I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution for this. The way I would naively go about it is to break down your fractions into multiple labels or text fields, one for the numerator and one for the denominator, stacked vertically with a separator line between them in a `UIStackView`, building a unit. You could then add this unit to another horizontal StackView, together with other units, to form a complete line. Alternatively, you could look into libraries for rendering math equations, like e.g. https://github.com/kostub/iosMath

Answer (score 1):

If you want an image of a simple fraction, you can render it like so:

```
func fraction(numerator: String, denominator: String, points: CGFloat, color: UIColor = .black) -> UIImage {
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: points),
        .foregroundColor: color
    ]
    let numeratorSize = (numerator as NSString).size(withAttributes: attributes)
    let denominatorSize = (denominator as NSString).size(withAttributes: attributes)
    let width = max(numeratorSize.width, denominatorSize.width)
    let spacing = points * 0.5
    let height = numeratorSize.height + denominatorSize.height + spacing
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
        // draw numerator

        (numerator as NSString).draw(at: CGPoint(x: (width - numeratorSize.width) / 2, y: 0), withAttributes: attributes)

        // draw denominator

        (denominator as NSString).draw(at: CGPoint(x: (width - denominatorSize.width) / 2, y: numeratorSize.height + spacing), withAttributes: attributes)

        // draw fraction line

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        color.setStroke()
        let y = numeratorSize.height + spacing / 2
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: y))
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

Thus, the following ...

```
let image = fraction(numerator: "42", denominator: "1000", points: 24, color: .red)
```

... yields:

[image]

---

But if you want to make this editable with a cursor, you might consider a series of separate controls. For example, this is a horizontal stack view with text fields for the numbers, labels for the `+` signs. The fraction is a vertical stack view, again with text fields for the numbers and a 1pt high `UIView` for the fraction line separating the numerator from the denominator:

[image]

You don’t need the borders for the text fields, but it just makes it easier to see what’s going on in the image above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wanted this function like under image! Can I look code what under the image? And Can I import StackView and TextFleid as a button? Maybe this mechanism seems to import StackView and TextFleid when push mathematical symbols. Sorry, This is my first programming of my life.